# How to hide "ships" in battleship without overlapping?

Tags: c#

Before hiding a ship object inside a button[,].Tag (the game tile) I check IF(button[,].tag == null) yet I'll still have ships overlapping randomly? It happens maybe 2/3 times over the course of 5 games on average? It also appears to be random, sometimes they will overlap at the end, in the middle, or completely covering each other.

I'm re-creating a battleship game and running into an issue when hiding the "ships". The ships are objects I've created and the tiles are buttons in a panel. I choose 3 random numbers, 2 are used for coordinates with the last random number deciding if the ship will be vertical or horizontal. Then I have an If statement inside a For loop that checks if the button[1st#, 2nd#].Tag == null, if it's null it'll place the ship object inside the button[1st#, 2nd#].Tag. The for loop will iterate through for the size of the ship either adding +1 to the 1st or 2nd number depending if the ships going horizontally or vertically.

```
private void HideShips() // method to hide the ships in the buttons
        {
            foreach(Ship s in AllShips)
            {
                //pick 2 random numbers
                int firstNum = rnd.Next(0, (19 - s.Size)); // game board is 20x20
                int secondNum = rnd.Next(0, (19 - s.Size));
                int rando = rnd.Next(0, 100);

                //decides horizontal/vertical at random
                if (rando > 50)
                {
                    //horizontal
                    for (int x = 0; x < s.Size; x++)
                    {
                        if (SeaButtons[firstNum + x, secondNum].Tag == null)
                        {
                            SeaButtons[firstNum + x, secondNum].Tag = s;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //vertical
                    for (int x = 0; x < s.Size; x++)
                    {
                        if (SeaButtons[firstNum, secondNum + x].Tag == null)
                        {
                            SeaButtons[firstNum, secondNum + x].Tag = s;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Before placing the ship objects inside the SeaButtons[1Num, 2Num].Tag I expect the program to test if the SeaButtons[1Num, 2Num].Tag == null? I have another method in this program called Stop(); which tests all the buttons .Tag value to determine if ships are hidden in them and ends the game + show the hidden ships which works fine?

Comment: Shouldn't it roll-back and choose another location if there's an overlap?

Comment: @PhilM Thank you. I can't believe I didn't see that lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, while you're testing to see if a particular button already has a ship place, you don't actually handle the case when it does. If you're placing a 5-long piece, and spot 2 overlaps with another, you won't set the Tag for that piece, but you will continue with the rest of the ship.

One potential solution is to create a function to test whether a piece can be placed, and, if so, do so. If not, choose another random spot. E.g.,

```
private bool CanPlace(int x, int y, int size, bool horizontal)
{
    if (horizontal)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            if (SeaButtons[firstNum + x, secondNum].Tag != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //same as above
    }
    return true;
}

private void HideShips() // method to hide the ships in the buttons
{
    foreach(Ship s in AllShips)
    {
        //pick 2 random numbers
        int firstNum = rnd.Next(0, (19 - s.Size)); // game board is 20x20
        int secondNum = rnd.Next(0, (19 - s.Size));
        int rando = rnd.Next(0, 100);

        while (!CanPlace(firstNum, secondNum, s.Size, rando > 50)
        {
            firstNum = rnd.Next(0, (19 - s.Size));
            secondNum = rnd.Next(0, (19 - s.Size));
            rando = rnd.Next(0, 100);
        }

        //decides horizontal/vertical at random
        if (rando > 50)
        {
            //horizontal
            for (int x = 0; x < s.Size; x++)
            {
                SeaButtons[firstNum + x, secondNum].Tag = s;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //vertical
            for (int x = 0; x < s.Size; x++)
            {
                SeaButtons[firstNum, secondNum + x].Tag = s;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One downside is you might get a lot of hits and need to frequently re-choose a location.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is than you don't check all button who will be use by your ship before assign them. 
Actually your program start place your ship and only remove a part when it find a button already use. So your ship can be cut in half.

Create a first loop who check every button and assign in a Boolean if all place are free and after that place your ship

Answer (score 0):

You can can take another approach and order fields instead od (x,y) coords like this

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 8 | 9 | 10| 11|
```

and then pick n numbers from 0 to (width*height)-1,
then transform it to (x,y) coords like this:

```
x = number % width
y = number / width
```